# Reading parameters passed with express

Tags: node.js, express

I have been messing with nodejs lately. I'm kind of new to it. I was trying to get parameters of the urls with Express. Im having some difficulties with reading the variable in html file which I sent to client. 
My code is like this:

```
app.get('/:username', (req, res) => {
  var name = req.params.username;
  console.log(name + " " + req.params.username);
  res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {username: name});
});
```

I can read variables trough console. They can be written down there. But I really dont have any idea about fetching this and using it in html file. I tried something like this:

```
$("#link").html(username);
```

Appearently it doesnt work. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: What template engine are you using? Can you show the html code?

Comment: You will need a [template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) like [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) or [ejs](https://ejs.co/).

Comment: can’t i pass without any template engine? or is it logical to use app.locals for passing parameters?

Comment: what would you think it should do without a template engine? Browsers don't do any kind of magical object value substitution with a predefined templating syntax: they just receive and then parse HTML documents. You need to make sure that you _send_ the final HTML, after doing the template substituting as part of your get request. You're using express so: read up on [response.render()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) works and make sure to tell it to use your templating engine of choice.

Comment: I was expecting something like $_GET variable in php. I am not eager to use jade or pug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can actually do this without a template engine that is if you are just carrying out this work for learning purposes. But if you want to carry out an important project don't try this, just use a template engine

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

app.get("/:username", ( req ,res ) => {

    const { username } = req.params;

    fs.readFile( path.join( __dirname, "public", "index.html" ), ( err , buf ) => {
        if ( err ) return res.status(500).send( "<p> something bad happened</p>" );
        const regexp = new RegExp(`{{\\s{0,}username\\s{0,}}}`,"g");
        const content = buf.toString().replace(regexp, username);

        res.status(200).send(content);
    });
})
```

lets assume your html file is like this

```
<!doctype html5>


<html lang="en">
    <head> <title> </title> </head>
    <body>
         <p> Your username is <a href="/{{ username }}"> {{ username }} </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** Please don't ever try this for a large project, you will just end up writing a template engine from scratch and a bloated one